# Delete certain day within recurring event

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, calendar

I am using [Fullcalendar.js](http://fullcalendar.io/) to develop an appointment app. Users will be able to create a recurring appointment in which they will be able to select a day for repeat weekly.

But now I am facing one problem. Lets say the user needs to delete the appointment for today only and leave the other recurring appointments to continue.

**Question**
How can I let an user delete a singular appointment from the recurring appointments within my application?

CODE:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

        defaultDate: moment(),
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        defaultView: 'month',

        events: [{
            title:"My repeating event",
            start: '10:00', // a start time (10am in this example)
            end: '14:00', // an end time (6pm in this example)

           dow: [ 1, 2 ] //repeat every monday and tuesday
        },{
            title:"My repeating123 event",
            start: '10:00', // a start time (10am in this example)
            end: '14:00', // an end time (6pm in this example)   
        }],
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do some stuff in fullcalendar.js main file.

just replace original function with below

```
function expandEvent(abstractEvent, _rangeStart, _rangeEnd) {
        var events = [];
        var dowHash;
        var dow;
        var i;
        var date;
        var startTime, endTime;
        var start, end;
        var event;

        _rangeStart = _rangeStart || rangeStart;
        _rangeEnd = _rangeEnd || rangeEnd;

        if (abstractEvent) {
            if (abstractEvent._recurring) {

                // make a boolean hash as to whether the event occurs on each day-of-week
                if ((dow = abstractEvent.dow)) {
                    dowHash = {};
                    for (i = 0; i < dow.length; i++) {
                        dowHash[dow[i]] = true;
                    }
                }

                // iterate through every day in the current range
                date = _rangeStart.clone().stripTime(); // holds the date of the current day
                while (date.isBefore(_rangeEnd)) {

                    if ((!dowHash || dowHash[date.day()]) && moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD') != moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')) { // if everyday, or this particular day-of-week // Add your condition for today here...


                        startTime = abstractEvent.start; // the stored start and end properties are times (Durations)
                        endTime = abstractEvent.end; // "
                        start = date.clone();
                        end = null;

                        if (startTime) {
                            start = start.time(startTime);
                        }
                        if (endTime) {
                            end = date.clone().time(endTime);
                        }

                        event = $.extend({}, abstractEvent); // make a copy of the original
                        assignDatesToEvent(
                            start, end,
                            !startTime && !endTime, // allDay?
                            event
                        );
                        events.push(event);
                    }

                    date.add(1, 'days');
                }
            }
            else {
                events.push(abstractEvent); // return the original event. will be a one-item array
            }
        }

        return events;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but how to use the function?Can you show me some example?

Comment: You need to change original function with new as mentioned in above answer. There must be a file named fullcalendar.js. Just open it and find 'function expandEvent(abstractEvent, _rangeStart, _rangeEnd) {' and replace whole function with function parameter and body with new function as mentioned in answer.

Comment: Thanks.i get you means . But what i means is in my html. How am i gonna to call the function? Can you show me the example ?

Comment: No need to call manually fullcalendar will automatically call this function while rendering repeat events into your calendar.